# Transforming a big/complex XML to an excel Spreadsheet with multiple Worksheets using XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xslt

Before anything I'm completly new to XSLT, I'm creating a Web Service to generate reports ,and I've been told to use XSLT to transform a realy complex XML (with multiple nodes all of them different from each other) into Excel , for it to be downloaded by the user.

I've searched around the web a bit but found little to no information thats useful to me since my XML varies so much from the examples shown on the web, Here's a little portion of my XML so you can have an idea.

```
<MODULO>
    <NAME>GeoDestribution</NAME>
    <VALUES>
      <ROW>
        <Ano>2016</Ano>
        <Comunitario>18928886.59</Comunitario>
        <Estrangeiro>19160686.33</Estrangeiro>
        <ExtraCom>231799.74</ExtraCom>
        <Inte>13404270.60</Inte>
        <percom>58.13000000000000000</percom>
        <PerEstrang>58.84000000000000000</PerEstrang>
        <PerExtracom>0.71000000000000000</PerExtracom>
        <PerInt>41.16000000000000000</PerInt>
        <Tipo>C</Tipo>
        <Total>32564956.93</Total>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <Ano>2015</Ano>
        <Comunitario>19008732.82</Comunitario>
        <Estrangeiro>19272372.85</Estrangeiro>
        <ExtraCom>263640.03</ExtraCom>
        <Inte>13214247.75</Inte>
        <percom>58.51000000000000000</percom>
        <PerEstrang>59.32000000000000000</PerEstrang>
        <PerExtracom>0.81000000000000000</PerExtracom>
        <PerInt>40.68000000000000000</PerInt>
        <Tipo>C</Tipo>
        <Total>32486620.60</Total>
      </ROW>
</VALUES>
</MODULO>
```

Does anyone know of any way to do this? I'm looking for information about how to do this like what steps i should take, i've just started working on this so i have nothing to show , and as i've said im completly new and kind of lost ...

hope you guys can help me! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before anything please note: StackOverflow is neither a code-writing service nor tutorial step-by-step guideline site, but a specific problem Q&A forum. Research this topic in-depth, make an earnest effort, come back with issues. Right now this is too broad and too extensive to answer here.

Comment: Before anything, i've never worked with any of this coding languages(xml, xslt) i'm also not asking for a detailed guide on how to do this, I'm just asking for a place to start , i've been searching for 4 hours straight now and i coulnd't find anything that could help me, it's either way to complicate code, or something that doesn't help me at all, like transforming XML to CSV, which doesn't work for me... I don't have any "issues" at the moment since i don't even know where to start , all the code i've written doesn't work.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: *which doesn't work for me* ... *doesn't work* ...these are unhelpful remarks. Be specific on what code you attempted, any errors, undesired results, then we can help.

Comment: But why not transform XML to multiple CSVs and then migrate CSVs into Excel worksheets? Use a general-purpose language like C#, Java, Python to run the special-purpose language, XSLT, possibly multiple scripts, and interface to an Excel API to import CSV data to build workbook.